# When I move to Pennsylvania, will the State Jury selection system keep track of when I was called to serve in my previous state?

Tags: united-states, jury, pennsylvania

## Background

I recently moved to Pennsylvania from Massachusetts. Three years ago in MA I was called for state jury duty.  I remember the officer there explained to me that being called for state jury duty does not count as being called for federal jury duty.  This means that I am still eligible to be called for federal jury duty.

However, given that I have moved states, a situation that I did not consider made me curious and I could not find an answer on a [Pennsylvania judicial district page](https://www.alleghenycourts.us/faq/default.aspx?show=D03JRrhb5rc=&id=hTGl3qrfCJc=).  Hence I wanted to ask here.

## Question

If I move to Pennsylvania from out-of-state, does my call to service in an out-of-state court system begin the exemption period from being called to a Pennsylvania state jury?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I move to Pennsylvania, will the State Jury selection system keep
> track of when I was called to serve in my previous state?

and

> If I move to Pennsylvania from out-of-state, does my call to service
> in an out-of-state court system begin the exemption period from being
> called to a Pennsylvania state jury?

This is a reasonable question. But the answer to both the title question and the question in the body text is "no."

There is no system of interstate cooperation regarding jury service in the United States. Your service on a jury in one state is not a basis upon which you can be excused from jury service in another state to which you move.

Comment: In other words welcome to the united states which behaves like a single country in some ways... And a bunch of mini countries in most of the ways that impact your daily life.